# Install action problems with installer class VS2008

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I am having a funny with the installer class provided with VS2008.

I have a commit action that compares two files in different folders and merges them. This is needed in order to be sure that some existing settings in the machine are not overwritten with a new version of the program. One file is in the ProgramData folder and the other is copied into the program folder. The action opens both and if it finds a new property in the program folder's one, it would copy it to the one in ProgramData.

It used to work well until I added a last interface dialogue prompting the user if it wanted to launch the program after closing the installer. The dialogue was necessary because a launch method in the commit section would not work because the software would be launched under SYSTEM user and would not find mapped drives from the user using the installer.

It seems that after adding this dialogue, the commit action does not even execute. I have added some MessageBoxes to follow the progress and they don't even come up. I am guessing that the commit action is launched before the program folder's file is copied and does not execute or it just doesn't execute.

Any ideas?

Comment: The following article can give you more insight on how actions get executed into an MSI. Please make abstraction from the product creating the MSI, as this does not matter, the same rules apply when it comes to scheduling custom actions. Hope it helps  http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/custom-actions.html

Comment: @Bogdan Thank you, I had read that article and others. That is why I don't understand why my action is not executed after adding the dialogue. It seems to me that the commit action should run after all has finished.